# C++ - Array of pointers to object, what is stored in STACK and what in HEAP?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm very new to C++ and I wish to make clear some points regarding memory management using the operator "new ..." and the operator "delete ...".

I will post some code of mine, and I ask if you please would correct my comments if they are wrong.

I'm also dealing with virtual functions and interface, which is clear by reading the code, and I also ask you if i'm approaching them the right way.

Then I have a more direct question, when should I use "new[] ..." or "delete[] ...", and how should I use them correctly?

PS: the output of code below is:

```
car built
motorcycle built
car has 4 wheels
motorcycle has 2 wheels
car destroyed
motorcycle destroyed
```

That's the main.cpp source:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class vehicle
{
    public:
        virtual
        ~vehicle()
        {
        }

        virtual void
        wheelNum() = 0;
};

class car : public vehicle
{
    public:
        car()
        {
            cout << "car built" << endl;
        }

        ~car()
        {
            cout << "car destroyed" << endl;
        }

        void
        wheelNum()
        {
            cout << "car has 4 wheels" << endl;
        }

};

class motorcycle : public vehicle
{
    public:
        motorcycle()
        {
            cout << "motorcycle built" << endl;
        }

        ~motorcycle()
        {
            cout << "motorcycle destroyed" << endl;
        }

        void
        wheelNum()
        {
            cout << "motorcycle has 2 wheels" << endl;
        }

};

int
main()
{
    // motorVehicle[2] is allocated in the STACK and has room for 2 pointers to vehicle class object

    // when I call "new ...", I allocate room for an object of vehicle class in the HEAP and I obtain its pointer, which is stored in the STACK

    vehicle* motorVehicle[2] = { new (car), new (motorcycle) };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // for every pointer to a vehicle in the array, I access the method wheelNum() of the pointed object

        motorVehicle[i] -> wheelNum();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // given that I allocated vehicles in the HEAP, I have to eliminate them before terminating the program

        // nevertheless pointers "motorVehicle[i]" are allocated in the STACK and therefore I don't need to delete them

        delete (motorVehicle[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: For every `new T`, you need a `delete`, and for every `new T[...]`, you need `delete []`. You code looks fine.

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Consider using smart pointers, e.g. `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, to manage the lifetime of your heap allocated memory, though.

Comment: What if I would have allocated motorVeichle[2] using new[]?

Should I have declared a pointer to a array of pointers?

Comment: No, `new[]` returns a pointer to the first element, so you'd still declare a pointer to vehicle: `vehicle* p = new vehicle[2];`. It is on you to remember to delete it with `delete[]`. You'd need a pointer to array if you were allocating an array of arrays: `int(*p)[5] = new int[5][x];`

Comment: @iMineLink You shouldn't.  What scenario would require a `new[]`?

Comment: But there comes the difference between using a pointer and an array right?

Better using `vehicle* pVehicle = new vehicle[2];` or `vehicle* motorVeichle[2]` ?

Using the first way I cannot release a single element of the array using `delete (motorVehicle[i])` right?

I start to be a bit confused...

Comment: PS: I mean, using `vehicle* pVehicle = new vehicle[2];` I can't do something as `delete pVehicle[1];` right?

Comment: @James Kanze
I think that in a more complex code, pointers can be reused or destroyed more easily than static arrays

Comment: @iMineLink I can't follow you.  Anything you can `new` you can (and must) `delete`.  It doesn't matter where the pointer is.  And what does `vehicle* pVehicle = new vehicle[2];` buy you that `std::vector vehicle(2);` doesn't.  (Just the opposite.  When you do `new vehicle[2]`, the pointers are not initialized.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know much of the data structures in C++...
I gave a look over `std::vector` and it's surely more convenient to use it instead of pointers with `new[]` for dynamic uses.
I was just "touching the ground" you know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory allocated with `new` is on the HEAP, everything else in on the stack. So in your code, you have

```
vehicle* motorVehicle[2] = { new (car), new (motorcycle) };
```

On the stack there is an array of two pointers `vehicle*[2]`, and on the heap are two objects, a `car` and a `motocycle`.

Then you have two loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

each of which create an integer on the stack for the duration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your code: the array of pointers is a local variable,
which would be allocated on the stack.  What the pointers them
selves point to is, in the case of your example, allocated
dynamically (on the heap).

Concerning the "more direct question": I've yet to find any case
where `new[]` should be used.  It's present for reasons of
completeness, but it doesn't really have any reasonable use.

Comment: In static cases like the one I posted you are right, but what if I want to allocate my array during runtime?

Coming from some Java experience, where you use: 
`Object[] array = new Object[n];` (you can use ArrayList that's true, but the let the garbage collector do some work...)
and from C where:
`int* p; p = calloc(sizeof(int), n);`

Here I think the more direct way is to use new[] and then delete[] then...
But if you say that it isn't very reasonable to use it, what should be used instead for dynamic memory management?

Comment: @iMineLink To have a dynamically allocated array, use `std::vector`.  C++ is _not_ Java; C++ has value semantics by default.  (And in Java, whether you use `ArrayList` or `new Object[n]` doesn't change anything with regards to the garbage collector.)

Comment: @iMineLink Perhaps more importantly: one important difference between C++ and Java is that in C++ you don't use dynamic allocation in C++ except when you really need it.  And you practically never need it except for entity object types, which have identity and are (possibly) polymorphic.  Arrays are not entity object types.